# Можно ли создать локальный почтовик?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, администрирование, openserver

Нужно создать 2 локальных почтовика (на одном компе на локальном сервере(использую open server) ). 
Мне нужны 2 локальных почтовых сервера для тестирования приложения.
Можно ли это сделать ? Что для этого нужно ?

Comment: Почтовик нужен на отправку или принятие почты ?

Comment: Можно, но какое именно взаимодействие по почте вы собираетесь тестировать? Возможно, есть способы проще.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, для тестирования проще всего будет сделать виртуальную машину с любым linux-дистрибутивом. И на нём установить, например, `dovecot` и `courier`. Это оптимальный вариант в плане настроек (после установки они уже настроены для локальной работы) и ресурсов. Если обойтись только командной строкой, без графической среды, то для этих двух почтовых серверов будет достаточно 256MB оперативной памяти.